# how to show a Word document property which is linked to SharePoint multiple line of text on multiple lines

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, word

We have a SharePoint document library which contain a field of type plain text multiple-line, as follow:-

[image: 229348-image.png]

and using Power Automate we are populating this field value inside a word document property as follow (the word document property is inside the word document Quick Parts):-

[image: 229372-image.png]

now if the user enters the following value inside the SharePoint item (3 lines of text):-

[image: 229320-image.png]

the result will be as one paragraph inside word document property without any new lines:-

[image: 229354-image.png]

Although inside Power Automate the value that will be passed from SharePoint will be as follow (with \n repressing new lines):-

[image: 229364-image.png]

any advice please, how i can show the text inside word document with new lines similar to how it is been shown inside the source SharePoint list?

Thanks

Comment: How are you updating content in word document? Using quick parts in SharePoint?

Comment: @GaneshSanap if i get you r point correctly, yes the word properties are added in the quick parts

Comment: Check [this thread](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Power-Automate/Populating-MS-Word-document-with-multiple-line-column/td-p/285536) & see if it helps.

Comment: @GaneshSanap not sure the solution is not clear on the link